# Interfacing to a Microprocessor Bus without an 8255

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor, interface, intel

There are 32 doors in a building each having a sensor attached with it. Each door outputs a signal 1 if it is open and O if closed. I want to design a pc based  system to display the condition of each door(open/closed) on the computer screen using parallel port interfacing by 8 bit data transfer at a time.

I have made a design using intel 8255 PPI and 8 MUX. PORT A of 8255 has been used as input and two pins of Port C has been used as the selector bits of each MUX.

My question is if it is possible to make the design without using 8255 PPI, by making direct connection with the microprocessor? If so, then how?

Answer (score 2):

Normally it would be tempting to call this too broad since you haven't specified the details of the processor or bus, but let's assume you already have figured out a way to connect the 8255 to it, and have the signals generated by that circuitry available to re-use.

Basically, you can use A1 and A0 to control your multiplexor, and the combination of /CS and /RD (logic OR assuming active low input) to enable a tristate buffer like a 74xx244 to drive the output of the mux onto your bus.  You would not need to write to any register at all, just read from one of the four addresses where /CS is enabled and the A1:A0 select the bank of interest.

Alternatively you could use a 1-of-n decoder IC to decode the address lines and select a distinct tristate buffer for each bank of inputs, though that does mean adding the capacitance of four chips to the data bus rather than just one.  Using something like an 74xx138 could potentially fold in some of the decoding of the base address, too.

You might find looking up the implementation of the parallel printer port on the IBM PC interesting - it *did not* use an 8255 but rather something like this, though there was an 8255 elsewhere in the system.

Early PAL/GAL logic arrays can be a flexible way of implementing the address decode, while later CPLDs or even 5v-era FPGAs can do the whole job.

Comment: So, the point is Microprocessor can be directly used to communicate with the peripheral device here without the need of 8255 PPI. Right? @Chris Stratton

Comment: Again, the problem is that you haven't given any details of the microprocessor.  But a general (if circular) rule of engineering is that if you can make one thing work *sufficiently* like another, you can probably use it as a replacement (circular, because for it to work you have to make it "sufficiently" alike that it will work)  So if you make something that drives the bus under the conditions when the 8255 would, using circuitry of comparable voltage and timing specs, and control it with signals that could control an 8255, yes, you can probably get it to work.

Comment: what is the main advantage of using 8255 ppi with microprocessor while communicating with peripheral devices over using micro processor without 8255? @Chris Stratton

Comment: That is the type of question which is considered "too broad" but common reasons included fewer individual parts to source and connect, familiarity, and (limited) software configuration, so you saw one on a lot of single board embedded or trainer systems.  Disadvantages included cost.

Comment: Although the OP doesn't mention it, sounds like another project centered around the ancient 8085 (now 30 years old) since that was the µP the 8255 was originally designed for.

Comment: It might have been designed for the 8085, but was widely adopted across everything with a similar bus architecture - the competing Z80 (in place of Zilog's Z80-PIO) , the subsequent 8086 and IBM PC and even some things that are less obvious matches.